# vim: showing listchars changes the screen wrapping

Tags: vim, line-breaks, eol

I noted that when I show up the EOL listchars in a text the linebreaks are losen

p.e.

```
 this is my text of this 
 message
```

becomes after set list ..eol

```
 this is my text of this mess
 age(EOL CHAR)
```

I would like to see the EOL characters without breaking the words at window border.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it sounds like this is a documented limitation of Vim. From the documentation of linebreak (the option which causes per-word line breaks instead of per-character):

> This option is not used when the 'wrap' option is off or 'list' is on.

Alternate solution: highlight end-of-lines. The simple one-time way would be to just search for them (/$). Beyond that, you can use highlighting:

```
:highlight endofline ctermbg=Green
:match endofline /$/
```

That'll give your EOLs green backgrounds. See `:help highlight-args` for more on how you can specify the highlight.

### Original answer

This is not the OP's actual problem, but could sometimes happen, so I'll leave it here for others to find when they search.

From the help on `'list'`:

> Note that list mode will also affect formatting (set with 'textwidth' or 'wrapmargin') when 'cpoptions' includes 'L'.  See 'listchars' for changing the way tabs are displayed.

From the help on `'cpoptions'`:

> L    When the 'list' option is set, 'wrapmargin',          'textwidth', 'softtabstop' and Virtual Replace mode (see |gR|) count a  as two characters, instead of the normal behavior of a .

`'cpoptions'` is all about vi-compatibility - are you launching `vim` as `vi`? Or are you 
manually setting any of those flags?  Check the output of `echo &cpoptions`, be sure to launch as `vim`, and if it's still set (no idea why it would be) you can unset the flag (`set cpoptions-=L`).

And of course, make sure that the settings for `wrap`, `wrapmargin`, `linebreak`, and `textwidth` are what you want.

Comment: I use GVIM.
I don't have textwidth/wrapmargin active because they do put a EOL character at the end of the line.

I tried to unset the flag settings cpoptions-=L 
but it still change the formatting with set list.

Comment: Oh, wow. It looks like `'list'` turns off `'linebreak'`. That's bizarre. I wonder if maybe it's because internally space becomes a real character (even if you're not showing it) and it can't tell where word breaks are?

Comment: thank you :match endofline /$/ is a good solution.
The only problem is that the end of line spaces is flickering when I enter text in a document ;)

Comment: Flickering, huh? My version of vim (7.2 with patches 1-394, and some extra features...) doesn't do that, though it does lose the highlighting if you type at the end of the line. It comes back with ctrl-L, so clearly it's not supposed to disappear!

Comment: @remio: I really don't think there's any better solution, and you said this one's good - you might want to accept the answer so it doesn't continue to show up as unanswered.

Comment: sorry, yes I forgot it. It's my first time here. 
Thank you Jefromi.