# Using linebreak and line options at the same time

Tags: vim, line-breaks

The documentation of `linebreak` says:

> This option is not used when the 'wrap' option is off or 'list' is on.

I find this unsatisfactory. **Is there a workaround to use certain `listchars` *and* `linebreak`?**

My ideal `.vimrc` looks like this:

```
set linebreak
set list
set listchars=tab:▸–,trail:·,extends:»,precedes:«,nbsp:⍽
```

… so I’m not actually interested in `eol:$`, which is presumably the reason why `list` conflicts with `linebreak` (that’s just my assumption but I see no other plausible reason for them to conflict).

There’s a [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2470833/1968) but in that the OP specifically wants the EOL mark, and the accepted answer addresses only this, so it’s not useful for me.

Comment: Whoever voted this as “off topic”: *We have a consensus* that questions about the configuration of code editors are on-topic.

Comment: True, this question shouldn't be closed as off-topic: apart from [this post on MetaSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user/25930#25930), on the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) is explicitly  mentioned that SO covers questions about _software tools commonly used by programmers_ .

Answer (score 1):

I would guess (but do not know for sure) that the current implementation cannot deal with the change of the displayed width when a Tab character shrinks to `^I` (assuming it has no value in `'listchars'`). In any way, I think Vim could be enhanced to do just what you want, though it might not be easy to implement. It might be worth to raise this request on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

There are little good workarounds; one could theoretically use the new *conceal* feature to emulate certain things of `:set list`, but it interferes with syntax highlighting and there's only one choice for highlighting.

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong: The tab character *doesn’t* shrink. The characters defined in `listchars` *fill the width* the tab character would normally take.

Comment: It does when you do `:set listchars=`, and by default there's only a value for `eol=$`.